# How to run a commandline in a terminal (Terminal, iterm2, etc)

Tags: c++, macos, terminal, iterm2

I am looking for a general and safe way to run a script string in terminals. There are dozens of Q&A on stack exchange, but *all* of them fail to field separate or escape properly, do not glob, quote etc since most of them pass the string through several levels of scripts (shells, osascript).

I need this in a C++ application so objc/cocoa is also an option. Any solution which does the job is a good solution. The closest so far are command files for Terminal.app, but it prints the path of the command file in the first line, and also works for Terminal.app only.

Comment: Part of your problem here is that you need a shell to run in. You're not just trying to fire up executables with passed arguments, you're trying to actually interpret another language. To do that, you'll need something like Terminal.app, XQuartz.app, etc. unless you're willing to implement your own shell in C++ or include the source from an open source shell (like the [Bourne-Again SHell](https://savannah.gnu.org/git/?group=bash)) in your project. But as it stands, this question seems far too broad.

Comment: Maybe I was unclear. I totally want a shell to interpret what I send. The problem of all the solutions is that the string is not perfectly forwarded.

Comment: So you want to open the Mac OS Terminal application and run some bash script line by line in the UI? It sounded like you didn't want to be dependent on Terminal.app from your question.

Comment: Maybe I just don't understand your question, but perhaps the simple [`std::system`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system) is what you are looking for?

Comment: @scohe001 yes. (although not sure what you mean by line by line). "Take a string and run it in a terminal as if I typed it on my own".

Comment: @heapunderrun no the shell should interpret the string. But good to know about std::system. ty

Comment: sorry @heapunderrun it's late. I meant I need the GUI

Comment: Maybe you can post what you have tried with `the closest command files` so that we have concret things to discuss.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little rough around the edges, but this will do what you want.

#### How does it work?

Since you want to do things in the Mac UI, the easiest answer will be Applescript. This program will create an Applescript file at `/tmp/terminal_runner.scpt`. It will then run the script with `osascript` by directly calling the executable at `/usr/bin/osascript` using `execv`.

Since `execv` is C code, things are a little messy. This also assume the string `cmd` you're running is properly escaped to fit in the Applescript script nicely.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

void run_cmd_(std::string cmd) {
    const std::string executable = "osascript";
    const std::string tmp_script_loc = "/tmp/terminal_runner.scpt";

    std::ofstream fhand(tmp_script_loc);
    fhand << "tell application \"Terminal\"" << std::endl
        << "activate" << std::endl
        << "if (exists window 1) and not busy of window 1 then" << std::endl
        // Assumes cmd is nice and escaped
        //                   vvv
        << "do script \"" << cmd << "\" in window 1" << std::endl
        << "else" << std::endl
        //                   vvv
        << "do script \"" << cmd << "\"" << std::endl
        << "end if" << std::endl
        << "end tell";

    fhand.close();

    char **argv = new char*[3];
    argv[0] = new char[executable.size() + 1];
    std::strcpy(argv[0], executable.c_str());
    argv[1] = new char[tmp_script_loc.size() + 1];
    std::strcpy(argv[1], tmp_script_loc.c_str());
    argv[2] = NULL;

    execv("/usr/bin/osascript", argv);
}


int run_cmd(std::string cmd) {
    int pid = fork();
    if(pid == -1) {
        perror("fork fail");
        return -1;
    } else if(pid == 0) {
        run_cmd_(cmd);
    } else {
        int status;
        if(waitpid(pid, &status, WUNTRACED) == -1) {
            perror("Error running command");
            return -1;
        }
        return status;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    std::string bash_cmd = "echo 'THIS IS A TEST'";
    int ret = run_cmd(bash_cmd);
    if(ret != 0) {
        perror("Oh dear...");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can `bash_cmd` contain double quotes ?

Comment: @Phil yes, but they must be escaped. ie `bash_cmd = "echo \\\"example\\\"";`